# Почему когда делаешь прыжок надо использовать GetKeyDown а не GetKey?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему при прыжке надо использовать GetKeyDown? Просто в любом случае идет проверка на касание с объектом и как только я делаю прыжок то переменная меняет свое значение на false и я не могу сделать второй прыжок, соответственно зачем использовать GetKeyDown? Я новичок и не понимаю разницы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Input.GetKey` - для определения "удерживает ли" пользователь клавишу

`Input.GetKeyDown` - для определения "нажал ли" пользователь клавишу.

То есть первое даже не вернёт `true` при простом однократном нажатии, только когда начнёт её держать. Второе - наоборот